# Completely lost with JavaScript events and OpenLight

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events

A customer gave me a set of functions to use in order to check on the client side whether OpenLight is installed or not. The Firefox and IE are working perfectly, but Chrome is always telling me that OpenLight is not installed.

However, I don't really understand how to trace this, because I am completely lost on what's going on. I Googled for the names of the events and I just get 0 results in Google :S For example, the following is the code to check in Firefox:

```
function isOpenLightInstalled() {
    try
    {
        var element = document.createElement("MyOpenLightDataElement");
        document.documentElement.appendChild(element);
        var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
        evt.initEvent("MyOpenLightEvent", true, false);
        element.dispatchEvent(evt);
        if (element.getAttribute("reply") == "1")
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch(err)
    {
    }
    return false;
}
```

What's that doing? What are those events? How does it know it's checking on OpenLight?

The following is the Chrome function:

```
function isOpenLightInstalled() {
    try
    {
        var customEvent = document.createEvent('Event');
        customEvent.initEvent('GCOLCustomEvent', true, true);
        var element = document.getElementById("GCOpenLightDataElement");
        element.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
        if (element.getAttribute("reply") == "1")
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch(err)
    {
    }
    return false;
}
```

Can someone please throw some light here :(

Answer (score 0):

> What's that doing? What are those events? How does it know it's checking on OpenLight?

1. It tries to create a `<MyOpenLightDataElement>` element and append it to the document (i.e. the webpage).
2. It creates an event called `MyOpenLightEvent`, then dispatches (runs) it.
3. That event is supposed to add an attribute called `reply` to the element in 1, such that it now looks like `<MyOpenLightDataElement reply="1">`.
4. If that works (i.e. OpenLight is installed and responding to such events), the function assumes OpenLight is installed correctly and returns `true`, and otherwise it returns `false`.

Your Chrome function is failing because as far as I can tell nothing with ID `GCOpenLightDataElement` is ever appended to the DOM. You might wish to try using the original function, and changing the catch statement as follows:

```
catch(err) {
  alert(err);
}
```

My proposal for Chrome, which may or may not work:

```
function isOpenLightInstalled() {
    try
    {
        var element = document.createElement("GCOpenLightDataElement");
        document.documentElement.appendChild(element);
        var evt = document.createEvent("Event");
        evt.initEvent("GCOLCustomEvent", true, true);
        element.dispatchEvent(evt);
        if (element.getAttribute("reply") == "1")
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.log(err); // just so we can see any errors with Ctrl+Shift+I
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Alerting err gives me: 'TypeError: Cannot call method 'dispatchEvent' of null'

Comment: I got the same, and that's what I was mentioning in the final paragraph. Unless your document automatically includes an element with ID `GCOpenLightDataElement` it will always fail. I don't use OpenLight or have any idea what it's documentation looks like, but I'd suggest using the first function up top and, if necessary, replacing things like `MyOpenLight` with `GCOpenLight`. Beyond that, I think we'd need more information on what your document looks like.

Comment: What do you mean with the original function? I got a bit lost here, that's the only function I have for Chrome :p

Comment: I see what you mean... There is no original function, there is one for each browser I think...

Comment: Right, I'm just thinking they messed up with Chrome, and your detection function needs to add in the part of the Firefox code that creates its own element. See my edit above. I can't guarantee it will work, but without something in front of me documenting how these elements are supposed to work, I can't do more than guess.

Comment: same here, can't find anything around.